# How can I split this string into an array?

Tags: c#, string

My string is as follows:

```
smtp:jblack@test.com;SMTP:jb@test.com;X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;
```

I need back:

```
smtp:jblack@test.com
SMTP:jb@test.com
X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;
```

The problem is the semi-colons seperate the addresses and also part of the X400 address. Can anyone suggest how best to split this?

PS I should mentioned the order differs so it could be:

```
X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;;smtp:jblack@test.com;SMTP:jb@test.com
```

There can be more than 3 address, 4, 5.. 10 etc including an X500 address, however they do all start with either smtp: SMTP: X400 or X500.

Comment: +1, an intriguing one - so much so that I've got no "real" work done for the past 10 minutes! =)

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: With the updated information, this answer certainly won't do the trick - but it's still potentially useful, so I'll leave it here.

Will you always have three parts, and you just want to split on the first two semi-colons?

If so, just use the overload of Split which lets you specify the number of substrings to return:

```
string[] bits = text.Split(new char[]{';'}, 3);
```

Comment: +1 never even knew about this overload.  Looks like Java has it, too!

Comment: There can be more than 3 address, 4, 5.. 10 etc including an X500 address!

Comment: They do all start with either smtp: SMTP: X400 or X500

Comment: Can you update the question with this information?  Will the SMTP entries always be before the other stuff?  Do you know how many entries there are before you parse this string?

Comment: I've updated the question, I won't know how many address and SMTP may or may not be first. Thanks

Comment: This solution isn't going to work based on the updated question.  I'm retracting my +1 but I'm still grateful for the information!

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest building a regular expression

```
(smtp|SMTP|X400|X500):((?!smtp:|SMTP:|X400:|X500:).)*;?
```

or protocol-less

```
.*?:((?![^:;]*:).)*;?
```

in other words find anything that starts with one of your protocols. Match the colon. Then continue matching characters as long as you're not matching one of your protocols. Finish with a semicolon (optionally).

You can then parse through the list of matches splitting on ':' and you'll have your protocols. Additionally if you want to add protocols, just add them to the list.

Likely however you're going to want to specify the whole thing as case-insensitive and only list the protocols in their uppercase or lowercase versions.

The protocol-less version doesn't care what the names of the protocols are. It just finds them all the same, by matching everything up to, but excluding a string followed by a colon or a semi-colon.

Comment: This nearly works but there is the assumption that addresses themselves do not contain the text smtp, X400 or X500.

Comment: Simple string formats really, really don't need regexes to split them IMHO, but this is a decent case for a regex.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't use Regex where string.Split will work (and that's why the colon processing is done string.Split), but as soon as you end up writing a chunk of code for string processing I think you should start to look at regex's for doing the same thing (they're better at it).

Comment: Then we're in violent agreement.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Split by the following regex pattern

```
string[] items = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Split(text, ";(?=\w+:)");
```

EDIT: better one can accept more special chars in the protocol name.

```
string[] items = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Split(text, ";(?=[^;:]+:)");
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the expressions involved if there is a space after the semi-colon.

Comment: I've tested it on http://www.regextester.com/ and it works(can identify the correct ";" in the string). Could be the flag or preg compatibility issue?

Comment: Try adding a space after the semicolon, but before the next protocol and it will fail to match that semicolon.

Comment: I see. I try to improve it. But how could the name of protocol start with a space?

Comment: I am just wondering, how this answer get downvoted but #483931 and #483931 get relatively more upvote?

Comment: Answer corrected and downvote removed. To answer your first question, people are lazy. If they see a question downvoted at all perhaps they don't bother reading it to upvote it.

Comment: I was not wondering that the answer not getting upvote. I was wondering how a downvote happen to an answer that answering the original and the revised question with less code, less hard-coded logic, less assertion and less problem.

Comment: Because it didn't actually walk the person through the problem. You said to split on those, but without also mentioning for example that you need to do a substring operation or such, they're unlikely to know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx
check there, you can specify the number of splits you want. so in your case you would do

```
string.split(new char[]{';'}, 3);
```

Comment: As specified, he doesn't know the number of splits that need to be made.

Answer (score 1):

**This caught my curiosity** .... So this code actually does the job, but again, wants tidying :)

*My final attempt* - stop changing what you need ;=)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fneh = "X400:C=US400;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;x400:C=US400l;A= l;P=Testl;O=Exchangel;S=Jackl;G=Blackl;smtp:jblack@test.com;X500:C=US500;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;SMTP:jb@test.com;";

    string[] parts = fneh.Split(new char[] { ';' });

    List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder address = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        if (part.Contains(":"))
        {
            if (address.Length > 0)
            {
                addresses.Add(semiColonCorrection(address.ToString()));
            }
            address = new StringBuilder();
            address.Append(part);
        }
        else
        {
            address.AppendFormat(";{0}", part);
        }
    }
    addresses.Add(semiColonCorrection(address.ToString()));

    foreach (string emailAddress in addresses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(emailAddress);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
private static string semiColonCorrection(string address)
{
    if ((address.StartsWith("x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) && (!address.EndsWith(";")))
    {
        return string.Format("{0};", address);
    }
    else
    {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, This almost works for me, apart from the semi-colon is removed from the x400 address which breaks it (I need to leave the semi-colons in or append one also) plus I've just dicovered one address has two x400 addresses! X400 (uppercase) indicates a primary address x400 (lower) secondary! Thks

Comment: That should be close enough... You could always add a conditional to "semiColonCorrection" that only adds the ";" back to the end for xNNN addresses, not smtp ones..

Answer (score 1):

Not the fastest if you are doing this a lot but it will work for all cases I believe.

```
        string input1 = "smtp:jblack@test.com;SMTP:jb@test.com;X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;";
        string input2 = "X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;;smtp:jblack@test.com;SMTP:jb@test.com";
        Regex splitEmailRegex = new Regex(@"(?<key>\w+?):(?<value>.*?)(\w+:|$)");

        List<string> sets = new List<string>();

        while (input2.Length > 0)
        {
            Match m1 = splitEmailRegex.Matches(input2)[0];
            string s1 = m1.Groups["key"].Value + ":" + m1.Groups["value"].Value;
            sets.Add(s1);
            input2 = input2.Substring(s1.Length);
        }

        foreach (var set in sets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(set);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Of course many will claim Regex: Now you have two problems. There may even be a better regex answer than this.

Answer (score 1):

You could always split on the colon and have a little logic to grab the key and value.

```
string[] bits = text.Split(':');
List<string> values = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i < bits.Length; i++)
{
    string value = bits[i].Contains(';') ? bits[i].Substring(0, bits[i].LastIndexOf(';') + 1) : bits[i];
    string key = bits[i - 1].Contains(';') ? bits[i - 1].Substring(bits[i - 1].LastIndexOf(';') + 1) : bits[i - 1];
    values.Add(String.Concat(key, ":", value));
}
```

Tested it with both of your samples and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try these regexes. You can extract what you're looking for using named groups.

```
X400:(?<X400>.*?)(?:smtp|SMTP|$)
smtp:(?<smtp>.*?)(?:;+|$)
SMTP:(?<SMTP>.*?)(?:;+|$)
```

Make sure when constructing them you specify case insensitive. They seem to work with the samples you gave

Comment: It's picking up the words smtp after the X400 address.

Comment: Are you checking the matches or the match groups?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of attempts.  Here is mine ;)

```
string src = "smtp:jblack@test.com;SMTP:jb@test.com;X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;";

Regex r = new Regex(@"
   (?:^|;)smtp:(?<smtp>([^;]*(?=;|$)))|
   (?:^|;)x400:(?<X400>.*?)(?=;x400|;x500|;smtp|$)|
   (?:^|;)x500:(?<X500>.*?)(?=;x400|;x500|;smtp|$)",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(src))
{
    if (m.Groups["smtp"].Captures.Count != 0)
        Console.WriteLine("smtp: {0}", m.Groups["smtp"]);
    else if (m.Groups["X400"].Captures.Count != 0)
        Console.WriteLine("X400: {0}", m.Groups["X400"]);
    else if (m.Groups["X500"].Captures.Count != 0)
        Console.WriteLine("X500: {0}", m.Groups["X500"]);   
}
```

This finds all smtp, x400 or x500 addresses in the string in any order of appearance. It also identifies the type of address ready for further processing.  The appearance of the text smtp, x400 or x500 in the addresses themselves will not upset the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
    string input =
        "smtp:jblack@test.com;SMTP:jb@test.com;X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;";
    string[] parts = input.Split(';');
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    foreach(string part in parts)
    {
        if (part.Contains(":"))
        {
            output.Add(part + ";");
        }
        else if (part.Length > 0)
        {
            output[output.Count - 1] += part + ";";
        }
    }
    foreach(string s in output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the semicolon (;) split and then loop over the result, re-combining each element where there is no colon (:) with the previous element.

```
string input = "X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G="
  +"Black;;smtp:jblack@test.com;SMTP:jb@test.com";

string[] rawSplit = input.Split(';');

List<string> result = new List<string>();
  //now the fun begins
string buffer = string.Empty;
foreach (string s in rawSplit)
{
  if (buffer == string.Empty)
  {
    buffer = s;
  }
  else if (s.Contains(':'))
  {   
    result.Add(buffer);
    buffer = s;
  }
  else
  {
    buffer += ";" + s;
  }
}
result.Add(buffer);

foreach (string s in result)
  Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: It looks like someone went around downvoting correct answers. I'm upvoting any answer I think is correct (especially answers that are downvoted with no explanation) and downvoting the question (because he keeps changing requirements).

Comment: 'Changing the requirements' is part of what this site is all about.  Sometimes the questioner doesn't exactly know what or how the question should be asked.  Seeing various answers come in helps them to refine the question.

Comment: Sure, but it's one thing to change the question... another thing to ask, get answers, change, and then downvote the correct answers to the original.

Answer (score -1):

here is another possible solution.

`string[] bits = text.Replace(";smtp", "|smtp").Replace(";SMTP", "|SMTP").Replace(";X400", "|X400").Split(new char[] { '|' });`

bits[0], 
bits[1], and
bits[2]
will then contains the three parts in the order from your original string.

Comment: Obviously, the example as it is will not match 'smtp' at the beginning. I think all the replaces should be without the semicolon, e.g. text.Replace("smtp","|smtp"). Final tidy up on the resulting can have a TrimEnd(';') and the split can be done with RemoveEmptyEntries to get rid of the first blank

Comment: my solution tries to cater for the other input string as well, which is `X400:C=US;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=Jack;G=Black;;smtp:jblack@test.com;SMTP:jb@test.com`

Comment: So will my altered one, it depends on how important the semicolons are, as yours is removing them.